# How to decrypt AWS KMS Double Encryption when downloading files from S3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-rds, amazon-kms

In our use case, S3 Bucket default server-side encryption is set to use KMS.

We’re generating the RDS MSSQL DB transaction logs and storing into S3 using `exec msdb.dbo.rds_tlog_backup_copy_to_S3` with `@kms_key_arn` parameter.

In the above scenario, the file that resides inside S3 is double encrypted. i.e. Encrypted first when storing the transaction logs to S3 by using `msdb.dbo.rds_tlog_backup_copy_to_S3` with `@kms_key_arn` parameter. Re-encrypted again with S3 Bucket default server-side encryption is set to use KMS.

Our requirement is AWS KMS encrypted database backup needs to be restored in an on-premises environment. The on-premises environment isn't aware of the AWS KMS key details because it's an external entity. So, we must decrypt the AWS KMS encrypted files prior to restoring them.

We understand that we don't need to specify the AWS Key Management Service (AWS KMS) key ID when you download an SSE-KMS-encrypted object from an S3 bucket. Instead, we need permission to decrypt the AWS KMS key. We have these IAM permission policies in place. However, our S3 transaction backup log file objects are double-decrypted. By using these IAM decrypt permission policies in place, it's decrypted only once which was encrypted by SSE-KMS and I could not find the solution to decrypt the file which was encrypted by using `msdb.dbo.rds_tlog_backup_copy_to_S3` with `@kms_key_arn` parameter.

Could you please suggest any solution to this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The metadata of every encrypted object holds the following details:

**x-amz-key**: This is the content encrypting key (cek) encoded in base64, encrypted. The cek is randomly created for each S3 object and it is always a 256-bit AES key. The associated cipher is always "AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding".

**x-amz-matdesc**: This is the customer-provided material description in JSON format (UTF8). It is utilized to identify the client-side master key (which is used to encrypt/wrap the generated content encrypting key).

**x-amz-iv**: This is the Initialization Vector (IV), which is randomly generated for each S3 object and encoded in base64.

To decrypt the x-amz-key, use the AWS KMS API as shown:

```
aws kms decrypt --ciphertext-blob "VALUE_FROM_METADATA_x-amz-matdesc==" --output text --query Plaintext
```

After downloading the encrypted file locally, use the Python script below to decrypt it:

```
python3 decrypt_file.py "decrypted_x-amz-key_from_above" "x-amz-iv-metadata-value" encrypted_file_from_s3.bak
```

This is the Python script to be saved as 'decrypt_file.py':

```
import base64
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
import sys

def unpad(data):
    pad_size = ord(data[-1:])
    return data[:-pad_size]

if len(sys.argv) != 4:
    print("Usage: python decrypt_file.py <Plaintext-KMS-DEK> <IV> <Encrypted-BAK-filename>")
    sys.exit(1)

block_size = AES.block_size
chunk_size = block_size * 1024
base64_key = sys.argv[1]
key = base64.b64decode(base64_key)
iv = base64.b64decode(sys.argv[2])

input_filename = sys.argv[3]
output_filename = f"{input_filename}.out"

cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)

with open(input_filename, 'rb') as input_file, open(output_filename, 'wb') as output_file:
    while True:
        encrypted_chunk = input_file.read(chunk_size)
        if len(encrypted_chunk) == 0:
            break
        decrypted_chunk = cipher.decrypt(encrypted_chunk)
        output_file.write(decrypted_chunk if len(input_file.peek(chunk_size)) else unpad(decrypted_chunk))

print(f"Finished decrypting {output_filename}")
```

Please make sure to replace "decrypted_x-amz-key_from_above", "x-amz-iv-metadata-value" and encrypted_file_from_s3.bak with the decrypted key, IV, and encrypted file path from your S3 respectively. Decrypted file will be saved with .out extension.